# how to convert epsg:6991 israeli grid to epsg:4326 wgs 84 python

Tags: python, coordinates, transform, epsg

i got data frame with columns ["x","y"].

"x" and "y" are coordinates for  epsg:6991 israeli grid

for example i like to convert `x=[212513], y=[617119]` coordinates,

to: epsg:4326 wgs 84

x=[35°7'2.734"] , y=[31°38'56.771"]

how can i convert Between the two types of coordinates?

Comment: use `pyproj` library. You already have the CRS, so it should be easy

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyproj
from pyproj import CRS
from pyproj import Transformer

crs = CRS.from_epsg(6991)
crs.to_epsg()
crs = CRS.from_proj4("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.7343936111111 +lon_0=35.2045169444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-24.002400,-17.103200,-17.844400,-0.33007,-1.852690,1.669690,5.424800 +units=m +no_defs")
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:6991", "EPSG:4326")
transformer.transform(220080, 634451)
```